# Unwanted result with two "Join" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently stuck on a problem with my database. I have a table of film reviews, a table of positives and another one of negatives. These last ones are linked to the id of an review.

Here are the positive and negative tables:

[image: Table positives]

[image: Table negatives]

I'd like to get this result:

[image: The result that I would like]

But I have this one instead:

[image: My actual result]

Here's my SQL code to get this result:

```
SELECT positives.libelle AS positive, negatives.libelle AS negative FROM reviews LEFT JOIN positives ON positives.review_id = reviews.id LEFT JOIN negatives ON negatives.review_id = reviews.id WHERE reviews.id = 1
```

Comment: You have to `FULL OUTTER JOIN` using the `reviewer_id`

Answer (score 1):

The result that you want is not really in a relational format -- because the column values on a given row really have nothing to do with each other.

MySQL does not support `full join`, so my recommendation is `union all` with `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and `group by` to bring them together:

```
SELECT MAX(positive) as positive), MAX(negative) as negative)
FROM ((SELECT p.review_id, p.libelle as positive, NULL as negative,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.review_id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
       FROM positives p
       WHERE p.review_id = 1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT n.review_id, NULL, n.libelle,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.review_id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
       FROM negatives n
       WHERE n.review_id = 1
      ) 
     ) pn
GROUP BY review_id, id
ORDER BY review_id, id;
```

Note this will return no rows if there are no reviews (positive and negative).  You can incorporate a `left join` if that really is a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any information about reviewer, why you join tables with reviewer? just limit tables by `review_id=1`.

The following query doesn't cover your need totally, however, maybe be helpful for your problem. Consider that *Union* is much more efficient that *Join*. If you can use *Union*, avoid using *Join*.

```
(SELECT positives.libelle AS positive,NULL AS negative FROM positives WHERE review_id=1) 
UNION
(SELECT NULL,negatives.libelle FROM negatives WHERE review_id=1)
```